# Spring Transactional annotation vs javax transactional

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, transactions

I am working with Spring 4.3.x and Hibernate 5.2.x. Since hibernate 5 JPA is standard way to user ORM with spring, I created a config to use Hibernate with JPA.

My spring configuration is,

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateExceptionTranslator;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.example.reports" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class SuperUserReportSpringConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendeorAdapter) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendeorAdapter);
        entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.example.reports.domain");
        entityManagerFactory.setPersistenceUnitName("onlineDB");
        return entityManagerFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        adapter.setShowSql(false);
        adapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.hibernate.dialect.DB2400Dialect");
        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    DataSource dataSource() {
        HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource();
        ds.setPoolName("hikariCP");
        ds.setDriverClassName(this.environment.getProperty("jdbc.as400.db2.db.driver.classname"));
        ds.setJdbcUrl(this.environment.getProperty("jdbc.as400.db2.db.url"));
        ds.setUsername(this.environment.getProperty("jdbc.as400.db2.db.username"));
        ds.setPassword(this.environment.getProperty("jdbc.as400.db2.db.password"));
        ds.setMaximumPoolSize(10);
        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager(emf);
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateExceptionTranslator hibernateExceptionTranslator() {
        return new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
    }

}
```

And I try to use `@Transactional` from javax.transaction.Transactional and org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional

In both the case, transaction manager is not working and I am getting error when trying to get child element from User entity,

`org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.example.reports.domain.User.userInetAddrs, could not initialize proxy - no Session`

I am not sure if I am missing any configuration.

Hibernate entity,

`@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
 private Set<UserInetAddr> userInetAddrs = new HashSet<UserInetAddr>(0);`

Service class with `@Transactional`

```
User user = superUserReportDao.getUserSecurityRoles(id);
user.getUserInetAddrs().forEach(inetAddress -> {

});
```

And DAO Method with `@Transactional`

```
public User getUser(int userSeqId) {
    return entityManager.find(User.class, userSeqId);
}
```

DAO Class transaction,

```
@Repository("superUserReportDao")
@Slf4j
@Transactional
public class SuperUserReportDaoImpl implements SuperUserReportDao {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="onlineDB")
    private EntityManager onlineEntityManager;
```

And Service Class,

```
@Service("superUserReportService")
@Slf4j
public class SuperUserReportServiceImpl implements SuperUserReportService {

    @Resource(name = "superUserReportDao")
    private SuperUserReportDao superUserReportDao;

    public void generateSuperUserReport() throws SQLException {

        // -- generate Customer Super user report
        generateSuperUserEmail(UserType.CUSTOMER);

    }

    @Transactional
    private void generateSuperUserEmail(UserType userType) throws SQLException {
...
```

And my main class,

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class SuperUserReportMain {

    @Resource(name = "superUserReportService")
    SuperUserReportService superUserReportService;

    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws SQLException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SuperUserReportSpringConfiguration.class);

        SuperUserReportMain reportMain = context.getBean(SuperUserReportMain.class);
        reportMain.generateSuperUserReport();

        ((AnnotationConfigApplicationContext)context).close();

    }

    public void generateSuperUserReport() throws SQLException {
        superUserReportService.generateSuperUserReport();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show the @Transactional annotation from your code? Also, can you show the sequence where the methods are invoked? I think you are running in a problem related to how proxies work in spring. Read the documentation where they say `In proxy mode...`: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html

Comment: Updated my post with how the @Transactional annotation used in DAO and Service

Comment: The `@Transactional` is on a private method and that will not work it has to go on the public method.

Comment: It WORKS !!!! .. I moved the `@Transactional` to class level... thanks :-)

Comment: You are trying to call a method that doesn't have the @Transactional annotation generateSuperUserReport(). To make it works, you have to annotate that method with transactional and use REQUIRE_NEW option.